# How to use UIKit localized string in my app

Tags: iphone, uialertview

We are building a iOS game, our company requires cancel button in a `UIAlertView` should always be localized depend on user's device language.

It looks like there is such a string in UIKit framework, how can I access it in my own app?

Or, any other way to create a UIAlertView with a localized cancel button?

Thank you

**Answer by myself:**

Problem solved by the following code:

```
NSBundle* uikitBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[UIButton class]];
NSString *language = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"] objectAtIndex:0];
NSBundle *languageBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[uikitBundle pathForResource:language ofType:@"lproj"]];
NSLog(@"%@: %@", language, NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(@"Cancel", @"Localizable", languageBundle, nil));
```

This read string files from `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework`

Following languages have different name between `NSUserDefault` and `UIKit.framework` folder: `fr en zh-Hans it de ja nl es pt-PT nb zh-Hant en-GB`. They should be handled by code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy method for Strings already in UIKit

```
NSBundle* uikitBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[UIButton class]];
NSString *cancel = [uikitBundle localizedStringForKey:@"Cancel" value:nil table:nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

### Swift 4:

```
    let bundle = Bundle.init(for: UIButton.self)
    let doneTitle = bundle.localizedString(forKey: "Done", value: nil, table: nil)
    for state: UIControlState in [.normal, .highlighted, .disabled, .selected, .focused, .application, .reserved] {
        buttonDone.setTitle(doneTitle, for: state)
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be using NSLocalizedString from foundation framework:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html

There is a nice tutorial about it: http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/iphone-applications-localization-guide/

Those predefined button names will be translated automatically by OS (Done in tab bar) and in uialertview you can set Cancel button title to be whatever you want...

```
     UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"title",@"titleKey") 
message:NSLocalizedString(@"message",@"messageKey") 
delegate:self 
cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"cancel",@"cancelKey") 
otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

Comment: key of my question is how to get NSLocalizedString(@"cancel",@"cancelKey"). It returns "cancel" when my device were set to Italian.

Comment: You have to create Localizable.strings files for each language... take a closer look at number 3. in tutorial i have linked for you...

Comment: we need to support all languages for just "Cancel", I don't think it's a good ideal to create hundreds of string file and translate them all

Comment: Nice to know `NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle` form your first like. Thank you.

Comment: The question is about using UIKit translations, saving doing it yourself for common words and phrases. See my answer for a nice easy way.