# How to get a localized title from system alert

Tags: ios, swift

How to get a localized title from system alert like a bluetooth permission request? I didnt find any methods how i can do it.

Comment: check this   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12181046/how-to-get-localized-cancel-done-and-etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get localized Cancel, Done and etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12181046/how-to-get-localized-cancel-done-and-etc)

Comment: I need to find the string like this "%@ would like to make data available to nearby Bluetooth devices even when you’re not using the app"